# OS error, No such file or directory: I am unable to install certain packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting the following error while installing a package for jupyter on visual studio code.

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Pravir Mishra\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\jedi\third_party\typeshed\third_party\2and3\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\ssl_match_hostname\_implementation.pyi`

I'm using the following command

> pip install -U ipykernel

Actually, this is the command that shows in the terminal. I have just clicked the button on the dialogue box of VS code, which told me this download was necessary to run my program. It comes up every time I try to run the program

can someone explain what this error means and how I am to resolve it? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: What commands are you using?

Comment: I have made the necessary edits

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command instead: `python -m pip install -U  ipykernel`